# Hibernate Criteria - Exclude groupProperty from select

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I would like to use a hibernate criteria object as a subquery on a second criteria, like this:

```
    DetachedCriteria latestStatusSubquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(BatchStatus.class);
    latestStatusSubquery.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add( Projections.max("created"), "latestStatusDate")
            .add( Projections.groupProperty("batch.id"))
    );

    DetachedCriteria batchCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(BatchStatus.class).createAlias("batch", "batch");
    batch.add( Property.forName( "created" ).eq( latestStatusSubquery ) );
```

The problem is that adding a groupProperty automatically add that property to the select clause on the subselect query and I can't find any way to stop this from happening.

The result, of course a DB error because the subquery returns too many values.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: And stil no answer? :'(

Answer (score 1):

Try like below sample,

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(CustomerCommentsVO.class, "latestComment"); 
            subquery.setProjection(Projections.max("latestComment.commentId")); 
            subquery.add(Expression.eqProperty("latestComment.prospectiveCustomer.prospectiveCustomerId", "comment.prospectiveCustomer.prospectiveCustomerId"));

 objCriteria = objSession.createCriteria(CustomerCommentsVO.class,"comment");
            objCriteria.add(Subqueries.propertyEq("comment.commentId", subquery)); 
List lstComments = objCriteria.list();
```

Comment: But actually u comaparing with primary table(groups.Primary table definetly will have 1 key) and taking the max, finally it become group itself.